# Spring Boot test configuration for multiple datasources

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-test

So I am trying to introduce some unit tests for my Spring Boot application and I am having a hard time trying to setup the config for the test environment. My application is configured to connect to two different Postgres databases as follows:

**application.properties**

```
spring.db1-datasource.jdbc-url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
spring.db1-datasource.username= admin
spring.db1-datasource.password= admin
spring.db1-datasource.driverClassName= org.postgresql.Driver

spring.db2-datasource.jdbc-url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
spring.db2-datasource.username= admin
spring.db2-datasource.password= admin
spring.db2-datasource.driverClassName= org.postgresql.Driver
```

**FirstDbConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.myapp.database.db1.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "firstTransactionManager")
public class FirstDbConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public FirstDbConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean firstEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(firstDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("org.myapp.database.db1");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.db1-datasource")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(firstEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**SecondDbConfig.java**

Not including it because it's quite similar. Targets `org.myapp.database.db2.repository`

For my basic test, I am trying to test a simple service that injects one of these configured repositories. This looks like that:

**MyServiceTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyService.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {FirstDbConfig.class, SecondDbConfig.class },
        loader= AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class
)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private FirstDbRepository dbRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
        // call to myService.method()
    }
}
```

Test fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set at ...
```

It obviously has to do with `hibernate.dialect` not being set but no idea why that is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Time to re-check the database. Is it running and listening on the localhost? Is it listening on port 5432? Do schemas db1 and db2 actually exist within it? Are the credentials correct? the reason is that this error implies that the necessary details cannot be autodetected - and thus you are requested to supply them yourself but that won't help because there is a problematic reason why they cannot be autodetected.

Comment: @Gimby everything is up and running and works perfectly in the dev environment.

Comment: But are the tests running on the same dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we need to include this hibernate dialect, try including these 2 lines in your application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to include this in application.properties file
spring.jpa.database=default

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment property `hibernate.dialect` since you're trying to get its value in your code.